# Configure Windows File History in Windows 10

Tags: .net, powershell, backup

Is there an equivalent in Windows 10 for:

```
Set-WssFileHistoryConfiguration
```

to configure the folders to backup using the Windows File History?

Comment: I too am looking for this functionality...